# MySQL / PHP - Partial comparison as duplicate match

Tags: php, mysql

What is the best approach to comparing partial data with full records as possible duplicate matches ?

For example, suppose you have a customer database that stores contact information, such as First Name,  Last Name, Address, City, Postal Code, and allows for multiple phone numbers for each record.

The goal, would be to locate all possible "matches" that certain data is a very close match, or identical to the information being entered.

Example:

```
Real Data Contains
First Name: Robert
Last Name: Smithson
Phone Numbers:  1111231234, 1111241235
Zip/Postal: 90210
```

I would want that record to show up in results, not only on an exact match -- but as follows :

- Rob Smith
- 90211
- 90120
- Bob Ithson
  = Bobby Son

Now I understand with the name variations above, I would need to have a separate table that I can use to intelligently differentiate between name variations / partials, however the goal is to have some sort of fuzzy logic in place that can reasonably ascertain the duplicity of records and/or return the most likely result given partial data.

I have considered the following methods :

- Hashing the record and using that for relative comparison : Won't work as has varies too much to be relative to the data stored.
- Chars in record stored in char array for comparison (aka, how many `A`'s, `B`'s etc) : This poses a problem as the variation between what is being looked for may not construe enough characters for a full spectrum analysis by character.

I am looking for other possibilities to programmatically approach this using PHP.

The database back-end will be in MySQL, and has no structure yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Levenshtein distance should solve your problem

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance

http://openquery.com.au/blog/levenshtein-mysql-stored-function

Comment: This does look promising.  It also looks like it is doing a string comparison so in the event of "Rob" vs "Robert" what would be the result given that "Robert" is twice the length of "Rob"

Comment: Distance between Robert and Rob is 3, as you need to change(add) 3 characters

Comment: This is a decent solution, but still needs a lot of work.  For example, two completely different names like  `Tim` and `Tom` return a distance of 1 which would cause a flag.  Will mark this as accepted as it is a bit better than the previous methods I have tried already, however if you can give some insight into other things I may do in order to increase the accuracy, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: In Levenshtein you can decide what is cost of operations. For example substraction might have cost of 10 points, while add/delete is 1 point per character. Should `Smithson` and `Smithsan` be considered as match?

Comment: I understand, however compare   `Bob` vs `Bab` .. clearly that would be a typo, and Leven would return 1, however `Tim` and `Tom` would programmatically return the same distance of 1.  In the case of Bob vs Bab ... I would want to have this, however in Tim vs Tom, that is likely not a typo.

Comment: There probably won't be a perfect answer for this problem. You might try to create list of accepted names and check levenhstein against them, but it will be quite slow and you need to maintain database. While in case of first name i think it's possible, with last name it will be nightmare.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51104/discussion-between-mleko-and-sanuel-jackson)

Comment: That is essentially what I was planning on.  Doing a names database of aliases, and returning a common alias so that `Dick` matches `Richard` exactly (extreme case), but `Tom` and `Tim` would pull `Thomas` and `Timothy` which would increase the distance and make typos like `Bob` vs `Bab` less obvious as `Bob` would return `Robert` and `Bab` would simply return `Bab`.  Will have to implement some sort of similarity search to locate potential typos. >> So complex.